# XPATH: trying to select button from element where span class contains certain text

Tags: java, selenium, web, xpath, automation

I'm trying to select the specific button of a class which also contains a certain text in it's span class. The website is setup to load random elements when visiting, so I can't use more specific paths I think.

Path to button

```
xpath = "/html/body[@class='js-page-layout-main']//div[@class='main-container']//div[@class='wishlist-selector wishlist-selector--product-listing']//button[@title='Adicionar a lista de desejos']"
```

Path to span

```
xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'Poucas unidades')]"
```

both expressions work for themself, but when I pipe them together the button of another element get's selected and not the button with the desired text in it's span class. I'm not exactly sure why this doesn't work..

EDIT:

piped together

```
xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'Poucas unidades')] | /html/body[@class='js-page-layout-main']//div[@class='main-container']//div[@class='wishlist-selector wishlist-selector--product-listing']//button[@title='Adicionar a lista de desejos']"
```

EDIT 2:
html

```html
<div class="col">
<article class>
<div class="wishlist-selector wishlist-selector--product-listing" data-qa="component wishlist-selector">
<form method="POST" action="/wishlist/add-item?sku=49850&amp;redirectUri=/computadores?price-range%3D1%253B37699%26price%255Bmin%255D%3D%26price%255Bmax%255D%3D%26sort%3D" class="wishlist-selector__form">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline" title="Adicionar a lista de desejos">
<i class="    material-icon align-items-center js-material-icon
" data-qa="component material-icon">
favorite_border
</i>
</button>
</form>
</div>
<div class="label-group" data-qa="component label-group">
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<a href="/mala-trolley-156-verbatim-frankfurt-preto-49850">
<div class="img-wrapper--ar-100 img-wrapper--ck-product-box">
<img class="lazyload img-fluid" ... >
</img>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="col">
<h6 class="mb-0"><a class="color-inherit text-decoration-none" href="/mala-trolley-156-verbatim-frankfurt-preto-49850">Mala Trolley 15.6&quot; Verbatim Frankfurt Preto</a></h6>
<div class="ck-product-box-sku">49850</div>
<div class="ck-product-box-short-description visible-listing-alt"><ul>
<li>Mala ideal para viagens de negócios de curta duração</li>
<li>Cinco diferentes compartimentos</li>
<li>Compatível com portáteis até 15.6"</li>
</ul></div>
</div>
<div class="col">
<span class="price price--sale-red h2 mb-0" data-qa="component price">
<span class="price__amount">
99,90 €
</span> </span>
<div class="availability-product" data-qa="component availability-product">
<span class="availability-text" data-qa="type_">
<i class="    material-icon text-success js-material-icon
" data-qa="component material-icon">
fiber_manual_record
</i>
<span> Poucas unidades</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: *"...but when I pipe them together"*. Show how you do it

Comment: xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'Poucas unidades')] | /html/body[@class='js-page-layout-main']//div[@class='main-container']//div[@class='wishlist-selector wishlist-selector--product-listing']//button[@title='Adicionar a lista de desejos']" @JaSON

Comment: Update the question.  Don't put the update in a comment

Comment: please add the html with the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `|` operator gives you the union of the two node sets. You want to use the second expression to filter the first one, so use:

```xpath
/html/body[@class='js-page-layout-main']//div[@class='main-container']//div[@class='wishlist-selector wishlist-selector--product-listing']//button[@title='Adicionar a lista de desejos' and .//span[contains(text(),'Poucas unidades')]]
```

**Edit:** After you updated the question, one can see that the `<span>` is not contained in the `button`, but they have a common parent `<article>`, so just move the condition on the span to the `<article>` element:

```xpath
//article[.//span[contains(text(), 'Poucas unidades')]]//button[@title = 'Adicionar a lista de desejos']
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me, getting "NoSuchElementException"

Comment: The match is case sensitive, check if there are no typos in your conditions. BTW usually one selects a button by its `id`, not a complex chain of conditions.

Comment: @dorjjj: I updated the answer based on your `HTML` example.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked! I really would have liked to select the button via id, but I couldn't find it. they didn't use it here probably.